# How to create a 2D tensor of points with PyTorch, each dimension going from 0 to 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to create a 2D tensor where each dimension ranges from 0 to 1.

For a 1D tensor, I can use:

```py
torch.arange(0, 1, 0.2)
```

This gives me:

```
tensor([0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
```

But, I want to extend this to 2D points. My desired output is [with the shape (25, 2)]:

```
tensor([
    [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.2], [0.0, 0.4], [0.0, 0.6], [0.0, 0.8],
    [0.2, 0.0], [0.2, 0.2], [0.2, 0.4], [0.2, 0.6], [0.2, 0.8],
    [0.4, 0.0], [0.4, 0.2], [0.4, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6], [0.4, 0.8],
    [0.6, 0.0], [0.6, 0.2], [0.6, 0.4], [0.6, 0.6], [0.6, 0.8],
    [0.8, 0.0], [0.8, 0.2], [0.8, 0.4], [0.8, 0.6], [0.8, 0.8]
])
```

How can I achieve this using PyTorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operation that you want is called Cartesian Product. Using torch you can achieve similar results to yours using torch.cartesian_prodd

```
torch.cartesian_prod(torch.arange(0, 1, 0.2), torch.arange(0, 1, 0.2))
```

it produces

```
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000],
    [0.0000, 0.2000],
    [0.0000, 0.4000],
    [0.0000, 0.6000],
    [0.0000, 0.8000],
    [0.2000, 0.0000],
    [0.2000, 0.2000],
    [0.2000, 0.4000],
    [0.2000, 0.6000],
    [0.2000, 0.8000],
    [0.4000, 0.0000],
    [0.4000, 0.2000],
    [0.4000, 0.4000],
    [0.4000, 0.6000],
    [0.4000, 0.8000],
    [0.6000, 0.0000],
    [0.6000, 0.2000],
    [0.6000, 0.4000],
    [0.6000, 0.6000],
    [0.6000, 0.8000],
    [0.8000, 0.0000],
    [0.8000, 0.2000],
    [0.8000, 0.4000],
    [0.8000, 0.6000],
    [0.8000, 0.8000]])
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I imagine there are multiple ways to do this, but another one (that's not particularly neat) would be to use [`repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html) and [`tile`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tile.html?highlight=tile#torch.tile):

```py
x = torch.arange(0, 1, 0.2)

twod_arange = torch.hstack(
    (
        torch.repeat_interleave(x.unsqueeze(1), 5, dim=0),
        torch.tile(x, (1, 5)).T,
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by this:

```
x = torch.arange(0, 1, 0.2)

xx, yy = torch.meshgrid(x, x) # Get 2D coordinate grids
xx, yy = xx.flatten(), yy.flatten()

result = torch.stack((xx, yy), dim=1) # Reshape and stack them together
```

This is the output:

```
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.2000],
        [0.0000, 0.4000],
        [0.0000, 0.6000],
        [0.0000, 0.8000],
        [0.2000, 0.0000],
        [0.2000, 0.2000],
        [0.2000, 0.4000],
        [0.2000, 0.6000],
        [0.2000, 0.8000],
        [0.4000, 0.0000],
        [0.4000, 0.2000],
        [0.4000, 0.4000],
        [0.4000, 0.6000],
        [0.4000, 0.8000],
        [0.6000, 0.0000],
        [0.6000, 0.2000],
        [0.6000, 0.4000],
        [0.6000, 0.6000],
        [0.6000, 0.8000],
        [0.8000, 0.0000],
        [0.8000, 0.2000],
        [0.8000, 0.4000],
        [0.8000, 0.6000],
        [0.8000, 0.8000]])
```